# pip3 using a different Python version than pyenv has activated

Tags: python, pip, virtual-environment

I've installed pyenv to activate Python 3.9, and that appears to have worked:

```bash
maxghenis@MacBook-Air-3 policyengine-canada % pyenv versions       
  system
* 3.9.16 (set by /Users/maxghenis/.pyenv/version)
maxghenis@MacBook-Air-3 policyengine-canada % python -V
Python 3.9.6
```

But when I run `pip3 install -e .` in [this project](https://github.com/PolicyEngine/policyengine-canada/blob/master/setup.py), it fails with an error message that suggests it's using Python 3.10:

```bash
× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [17 lines of output]
      Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:
      AssertionError:
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 351, in <module>
```

How can I ensure that `pip3` uses 3.9?

Comment: Try ```python -m pip3 install -e .```
Alternatively u can try pip instead of pip3

Comment: you can alternatively use ```pyenv pip install -e .```

Comment: `pythom -m pip` is the best way to make sure you are running the correct pip for the current `python`

Comment: It sounds like your `PATH` is set up in a way that your homebrew python is getting used instead of pyenv's, possibly due to it getting set differently in non-login/non-interactive shells. Check your `.*rc` and `.*profile` files (are you using bash or zsh?). The pyenv shims should come before homebrew in `PATH`.